# Count the number of words in word_lst that start with the letter "H" (note the capitalization). Store this into the variable h_count

Tags: list, capitalization

word_lst = ["Hello", "activecode", "Java", "C#", "Python", "HTML and CSS", "Javascript", "Swift", "PHP"]

I"m super stuck on how to do this by counting only the first letter of each word and it has to be a capital H.

Comment: Can you give us some more information?  What language are you programming in?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

One solution that should work in almost any programming language:

1. Create a counter variable (h_count) and initialize to 0.
2. Iterate through the elements of the list.
3. Check each element if the first letter matches the 'H' character and increment the counter by 1 if it matches.